# Connection to SQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

i have a windows server 2008 set up as a database server, i used to have MS SQL 2005 installed on it, due to some client changes i installed SQL 2008 R2 along with the 2005, the R2 is with a named instance. when i tried to connect an application to the 2008 R2 database, i get:

> network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)

i am sure of the ports as i checked the named instance configuration on the DB server, i also telnet the dynamic IP from the application server and it is going through. i also tried to connect a copy of the application from a demo server i have with the same configuration as the application server and it was successful. from the application server it is not, any suggestions?

Comment: Check you firewall settings on DB server? Maybe need to open specific port for SQL Server.

Comment: Check whether SQL Server is started or not ?

Comment: Thank you, i did check the ports and made sure that the server is running, still the same results

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps in below link to get solution

[http://relyonsoft.com/techsupport/?p=1045][1]

Comment: thank you Kavin, i did follow all steps above on the SQL 2008 R2, i am still unable to connect to it, i am able to connect to the SQL 2005

Comment: Update: it seems that when i used the IP address of the server rather than  the server name, it worked.

Comment: If you want to use server name to connect to an instance, then must enable and start SQL Browser service. Check whether is it started